# write sql query to calculate product

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Here is a table with three columns: user_id, product_id, rating,

This is the table:

```
user_id    product_id    rating
u0         p0            3
u0         p1            2
u1         p0            1
u1         p1            4
u2         p0            2
u2         p1            3
```

if two different customers both rated the same two products, then calculate the dot product of their ratings as follows:
u0 and u1 both rated product p0 and p1, the result should be: 3 * 1 + 2 * 4 = 11

and the result table:

```
u0  u1  3*1+2*4=11 
u0  u2  3*2+2*3=12 
u1  u2  1*2+4*3=14
```

How can I write a query to get it?

Comment: choose any one of MySQL & SQL-Server which both are different.

Comment: @roastedpotato: are there any additional conditions, like limiting it to certain users / products? Also, do you really need the first and second column to have the user_ids?

Comment: You are not clear. You have not explained. What is output as a function of what is input? (Why is that the output for the example input? What if there are other users & products? What "the two products"?) Also, what have you tried? Please read & act on [mcve].

Comment: This is only the tiniest bit less unclear. Explain how to map the input to vectors. Eg you don't mean "the values are stored as [a] sparse vector", you mean something like "the table represents two vectors via ... sparse ....". Eg (mathematical 1-D) vectors are typically ordered lists, and based on your formula & mention of dot product, they are a user & product vector, but tables are not ordered, so how are the factors getting paired? Use the English language to write enough complete sentences with proper punctuation & grammar that use enough words to refer to things to explain what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

T-SQL/SQL Server

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [user_id] VARCHAR(2)
   ,[product_id] VARCHAR(2)
   ,[rating] DECIMAL(9,2)
);


INSERT INTO @DataSource ([user_id], [product_id], [rating])
VALUES ('u0', 'p0', 3)
      ,('u0', 'p1', 2)
      ,('u1', 'p0', 1)
      ,('u1', 'p1', 4);

WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT [product_id]
          ,EXP(SUM(LOG([rating]))) AS [value]
    FROM @DataSource
    GROUP BY [product_id]
)
SELECT SUM([value])
FROM DataSource;
```

Answer (score 1):

The first two columns of the desired result make no sense -  what if there were multiple users?

So, ignoring that bit...

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(subtotal)) total 
  FROM
     ( SELECT product_id
     , EXP(SUM(LOG(rating))) subtotal
  FROM my_table
 GROUP 
   BY product_id
  ) n;
```

Sqlfiddle of same: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3c9dac/3

Oh, this is almost an exact duplicate of the earlier answer. As it was posted first, if you’re minded to accept this, accept that instead.

Comment: you both wrote in mysql, is it possible to write in t-sql?

Comment: Not knowing tsql, I couldn’t say.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Solution:

```
SELECT SUM(m.product_rating)
FROM (
    SELECT EXP(SUM(LOG(COALESCE(rating,1))) AS product_rating
    FROM table
    GROUP BY product_id
    /*this query multiplies the ratings by product*/
) AS m
GROUP BY NULL
```

**Edit**:

If you want only certain products, add

```
WHERE product_id IN('p0', 'p1', ...)
```

in the inner query.
If you want only certain users, add

```
WHERE user_id IN('u0', 'u1', ...)
```

in the outer query.

Comment: Please don't answer unclear questions. It just promotes poor questions & poor answers and long discussions. Comment & downvote & close vote until they are clear. What you don't have the rep for, don't do.